# Resizing dimensions of the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

In my mobile application I wish to start programatically an Fragment over parent activity.

For this in my activity class I use for OnClickListener anonym instance (for some button) this code:

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Class of my fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment.
In xml file from res/layout folder I use RelativeLayout.

Finally I want to look like in below drawing.
[image]

The problem is that when it starts fragment covering the entire screen, that parent activity. How do I resize as desired?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the layout_width and layout_height and give it the values you want, or in the layout of the Fragment set some margins, or use layout_marginTop, layout_marginLeft, etc, or padding. Maybe choices you have. Just remember to set the layout_gravity="center" of the fragment or the container that holds it.